# Way to retrieving index of changed Object in ArrayList?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a web app that uses dataTables in JSF and Primefaces features so that it may perform some more dynamic functions. In the dataTable I have rows that contain editable data. My ultimate goal is to have users be able to edit that data, click a save button, and update statements will be executed to replace what's present in the database. The problem is that at this time I do not know how to detect changes in objects within an arrayList.

I have made an example to see if anyone can solve my dilemma. Hear I have code that makes a dataTable and in the dataTable are objects from an ArrayList, each object containg three different strings. The objects are editable in the datatable. I need to be able to at minimum retrieve the ArrayList index of the object that is edited on the page. With that, I could form a new list of edited objects, and write up a method that executes a batch update on only the objects edited (an object in my scenario is equivalent to a row of data in the database) . My previous method was iterating through the entire ArrayList and updating all objects (rows), but, as the list grows large, this becomes very expensive to do. Right now I have a primefaces method onCellEdit, which tells me a previous value and the value it was changed to, but no way of pinpointing the object changed. Any help would be appreciated. The code below is set up so that it may be copied and pasted and executed.

Edit:
In my situation, I do not need to update the ArrayList. That is done automatically using the inputs on the pages and the getter and setters for the bean. What I need to do is know which **objects (rows) are edited** so that I may pull them aside and perform a database update, where i only update what is edited. The ArrayList is a mirror of what is in the database, but the goal here is to update the database to mirror the edited ArrayList, **without** having to iterate through the entire List.

Prod.java

```
public class Prod{

private String value1;

private String value2;

private String value3;

public String getValue1() {
    return value1;
}

public void setValue1(String value1) {
    this.value1 = value1;
}

public String getValue2() {
    return value2;
}

public void setValue2(String value2) {
    this.value2 = value2;
}

public String getValue3() {
    return value3;
}

public void setValue3(String value3) {
    this.value3 = value3;
}

}
```

Listen.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.event.CellEditEvent;

import com.product.inventory.beans.Prod;



@ManagedBean(name = "listen")

@SessionScoped
public class Listen{

 private ArrayList<Prod> products;

 boolean firstEdit = true;


public Listen(){

}

public ArrayList<Prod> setup(){


    ArrayList<Prod> result = new ArrayList<>();     

    int numObject = 100;

    int iterations = 0;


    while( iterations < numObject){

        Prod prod = new Prod();

        prod.setValue1("A" + iterations);
        prod.setValue2("B" + iterations);
        prod.setValue3("C" + iterations);

     result.add(prod);

     iterations = iterations + 1;
    }

    return result;

}

public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {

  Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue();

    if(newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, 
"Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

if(isFirstEdit()){

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new 
FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                "Note",  "To confirm changes, please select 'Save Changes' 
or they will not be saved.") );

        this.setFirstEdit(false);

}

}

public void goTest(){

    System.out.println("Initializing...");

    this.products = setup();

    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext();

    try {

         ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath()
                    + "/test.xhtml");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Table Structure Made");

}

public boolean isFirstEdit() {
    return firstEdit;
}

public void setFirstEdit(boolean firstEdit) {
    this.firstEdit = firstEdit;
}

public ArrayList<Prod> getProducts() {
    return products;
}

public void setProducts(ArrayList<Prod> products) {
    this.products = products;
}

}
```

test.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>

<h:form id="form" method="post">

<p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" sticky="false">
    </p:growl>
    <div >

        <p:dataTable id="products" var="prod" value="#{listen.products}"
             scrollable="true" scrollHeight="900" 
             editable = "true" editMode="cell" widgetVar= "prodCell">

            <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{listen.onCellEdit}" 
            update=":form:msgs"/>

            <p:column filterBy="#{prod.value1}" filterMatchMode="contains" 
            style = "width: 300px;" headerText="Name">

                <p:cellEditor>

                    <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="# 
                    {prod.value1}" /></f:facet>

                    <f:facet name="input"><p:inputTextarea rows="2" value="# 
                    {prod.value1}" style = "width: 96%"/></f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>

            </p:column>

            <p:column style = "width: 140px;" headerText="Vendor">

                <p:cellEditor >

                    <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="# 
                    {prod.value2}" /></f:facet>

                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{prod.value2}" 
                        style="width:100%">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="Y" itemLabel="Yes"/>
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="N" itemLabel="No"/>
                        </h:selectOneMenu>

                    </f:facet>

                </p:cellEditor>

            </p:column>


            <p:column style = "width: 275px;" headerText="Version Release">

                <p:cellEditor>  
                    <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="# 
                    {prod.value3}" /></f:facet>

                    <f:facet name="input"><p:inputTextarea rows="1" value="# 
                    {prod.value3}" style = "width: 96%"/></f:facet>

                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column> 

            <f:facet name="footer">
            <div align = "left">
            <p:commandButton value="post" action="#{tables.showChange}" 
            ajax="false"></p:commandButton>
            </div>
            </f:facet>


        </p:dataTable>

    </div>

     <p:contextMenu for="products" widgetVar="pMenu">   
    <p:menuitem value="Edit Cell" icon="pi pi-search" 
     onclick="PF('prodCell').showCellEditor();return false;"/>  
    <p:menuitem value="Hide Menu" icon="pi pi-times" 
     onclick="PF('pMenu').hide()"/>  
</p:contextMenu> 

</h:form>
```

Index.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>

<h:form method="post">

<h:commandButton value = "Contact Spreadsheet" ajax="false" 
action="#{listen.goTest}" ></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: May have figured out a way to solve my problem, but using logic. Not any observable or listener methods. If anyone has any possible solution let me know!

Comment: This is exactly what the PFE Sheet is for: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/sheet/basicUsage.jsf  as you edit each cell it tracks exactly what rows were edited so you can know exactly what was changed and just update those records and commit them.

Comment: Thanks Melloware. I was unaware that this existed. A question about the sheet. When the method sheet.getUpdates() is executed on the managed bean, does the resulting list contain all of the changed row objects?

Comment: Yes the sheet.getUpdates contains all of the rows that were modified since the last time you called sheet.commitUpdates();  So you can control when to flush the updates.

Comment: Thanks so much for that. I would accept that as an answer if you post it as one.

Comment: OK I posted as a solution thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you want is the [PrimeFaces Extensions Sheet](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/sheet.jsf) component for the behavior you are looking for.

Sheet fills a need that the PrimeFaces Datatable with in-cell editing does not fill. It can handle a large amount of data with editing single cells without submitting the entire sheet. Provides familiar spreadsheet navigation with TAB and SHIFT+TAB and familiar spreadsheet experience.

**Features include:**

- Fast In-Cell Editing and Validation
- Copy/Paste Range Selection including Copy/Paste and Fill
- Sorting
- Filtering
- Fixed Columns and Rows
- Resizable Columns and Rows
- Movable Columns and Rows
- Ajax Updates and Validation

Based on [Handsontable](https://handsontable.com/) by Handsoncode.